# how to change from debug mode to normal mode in jDeveloper ?

Tags: jdeveloper

i don't want the console to open as well when i launch my jDev.

[jDev view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHL8Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows use the jdevw.exe file.